# Column is not indexed even though it is. PreparedStatement inside

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, prepared-statement

I'm really struggling with a bug that did not appear on my dev environment, only once deployed in test.

I'm using a prepared Statement to run around 30 000 query in a row. The query check for the similarity of a string with what's in our database, using the oracle fuzzy method.

The column checked is indexed, but, don't know why, it fails randomly after some iterations, saying that index does not exists.

I don't understand what's going on, as the index really exists. My method never rebuild or delete the index so there is no reason for this error to appear ...

```
public List<EntryToCheck> checkEntriesOnSuspiciousElement(List<EntryToCheck> entries, int type,int score, int numresults, int percentage) throws Exception {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statementFirstName = null;
    PreparedStatement statementLastname = null;

    int finalScore = checkScore(score);
    int finalNumResults = checkNumResults(numresults);
    int finalPercentage = checkPercentage(percentage);
    try {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    StringBuilder requestLastNameOnly = new StringBuilder("SELECT SE.ELEMENT_ID, SE.LASTNAME||' '||SE.FIRSTNAME AS ELEMENT, SCORE(1) AS SCORE ");
    requestLastNameOnly.append("FROM BL_SUSPICIOUS_ELEMENT SE ");
    requestLastNameOnly.append("WHERE CONTAINS(SE.LASTNAME, 'fuzzy({' || ? || '},' || ? || ',' || ? || ', weight)', 1)>? ");
    requestLastNameOnly.append((type > 0 ? "AND SE.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID = ? " : " "));
    requestLastNameOnly.append("ORDER BY SCORE DESC");

    statementLastname = connection.prepareStatement(requestLastNameOnly.toString());
    for (EntryToCheck entryToCheck : entries) {
            ResultSet rs;
            boolean withFirstName = (entryToCheck.getEntryFirstname() != null && !entryToCheck.getEntryFirstname().equals("")); 
                statementLastname.setString(1, entryToCheck.getEntryLastname().replaceAll("'","''"));
                statementLastname.setInt(2, finalScore);
                statementLastname.setInt(3, finalNumResults);
                statementLastname.setInt(4, finalPercentage);

                if(type > 0){
                    statementLastname.setInt(5, type);
                }
                System.out.println("Query LastName : " +  entryToCheck.getEntryLastname().replaceAll("'","''") );
                rs = statementLastname.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                Alert alert = new Alert();
                alert.setEntryToCheck(entryToCheck);
                alert.setAlertStatus(new AlertStatus(new Integer(AlertStatusId.NEW)));
                alert.setAlertDate(new Date());
                alert.setBlSuspiciousElement(new BlSuspiciousElement(new Integer(rs.getInt("ELEMENT_ID"))));
                alert.setMatching(rs.getString("ELEMENT") + " (" + rs.getInt("SCORE") + "%)");
                entryToCheck.addAlert(alert);
                }

        }
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            DAOUtils.closeConnection(connection, statementLastname);
        }

        return entries;
}
```

Really don't know what to look at ...

Thanks !

F

Answer (score 1):

I never used Oracle text tables but my advice is:
Make sure that no one else is executing DDL statements on the table simultaneously.
Also, make sure that, index you have is context index.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index for your column where you want to apply search

........................................

CREATE INDEX "MTU219"."SEARCHFILTER" ON "BL_SUSPICIOUS_ELEMENT " ("LASTNAME") 
   INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"  PARAMETERS ('storage CTXSYS.ST_MTED_NORMAL SYNC(ON COMMIT)');

..........................................